# How to populate embedded Doctrine document into Zend fieldset?

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework2, fieldset, doctrine-odm, zend-form2

I use ZF2+Doctrine+DoctrineMongoODM module. I have `Person` document embedded into `House` document:

```
/**
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class Custelement{
    /** @ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Person") */
    protected $person;
```

So

```
#Document is binded to form
$form->bind($document);. 
#Common hydrator is used
$form->setHydrator(new \DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject($docManager));
```

Common fields of a document `House` are saved and populated great. I use fieldset with name `person` to edit embedded document fields, so there is a set of input elements with `name=person[firstName]` and `name=person[lastName]`.

Embedded document's fields are saved but not populated into form.

I found a workaround - just get values by `$vals = (array) $element->getValue();` for fieldset object and then

`$name = preg_replace("/^(.*)\[(.*)\]$/", "\\2", $elem->getName());
$elem->setValue($vals[$name]);` for each fieldset element.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

With aid of zf manuals I found what I have missed. I should set Hydrator and Object for the fieldset: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#creating-fieldsets

```
$person->setHydrator(
    new \DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject($docManager)
);
$person->setObject(new \Cab\Document\Person());
```

I thought that I should call setObject with filled object. Not. Just empty object.